# How to check laravel spatie permission in api controller for current login user?

Tags: laravel

I am using spatie/laravel-permission for permission checking.
How can i check permission by

```
Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo($permissionName)
```

in API controllers ?

Anyone can help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: if i understand you well , you can use http://jwt-auth.com in this api

Comment: What do you mean with „how can I check permissions?“ do you already have a permission table and Model?

Comment: yes i have permission table and roles table by integrate spatie.

Answer (score 14):

I think you can do: `auth()->user()->can('permission')`

Answer (score 1):

This work its in Laravel 8:

```
if( Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo('route.name') ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$this->authorize('permission_name');` in the controller